# Surface content colour slightly different to expected

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

My `Text` colour is not the same as that defined in the theme despite it being inside `Surface`; it appears almost the same but not quite.

[image]

This simplistic sample layout is bare bones:

```
MyTheme {
    Surface {
        Column(Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "This is a line of text, uses surface",
            )
            Text(
                text = "This is a line of text, forced white",
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My theme is simple:

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = DarkColours,
        ...,
        content = content
    )
}

internal val DarkColours = darkColors(
    surface = Color(0xFF043143),
    onSurface = Color.White,
    ... // None of the other colours are close to off-white
)
```

Even if I explicitly specify the colours to use in the surface, the top Text is still off-white (no change):

```
Surface(
    color = Color(0xFF043143),
    contentColor = Color.White
) { ... }
```

Elevation is 0.0dp and uses `DefaultElevationOverlay` so shouldn't have any effect on `contentColor`

`LocalContentColor.current` reports `Color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` when printed by the first `Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out while typing this question up so figured I'd share it.

`LocalContentAlpha` was set to 0.87 inside the contents of `MaterialTheme`.  This is because of its line

```
LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high,
```

which ultimately resolves to this due to the fact that I'm using a material Color scheme with `isLight = false` (thanks to `darkColors`).

```
private object LowContrastContentAlpha {
    const val high: Float = 0.87f
    const val medium: Float = 0.60f
    const val disabled: Float = 0.38f
}
```

A workaround is to re-set alpha back to 1.0:

```
MaterialTheme(
    colors = DarkColours,
    ...
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        // Undo our "dark" colours triggering Material theme
        // to use a low contrast alpha (87%).
        LocalContentAlpha provides 1.0f,
        content = content
    )
}
```

(or just use `lightColors` / set `isLight = true` if you can afford to do this)

This kind of blows my mind, that Material would just change the alpha of literally *all* of my app's content - I can't find any doc on why it does this either in the material spec!

Comment: I'm using lightColors, but even that is not enough. ContenAlpha.high also gets alpha based on luminance. If it is higher than 0.5 it gets the high contrast alpha and otherwise gets the low contrast alpha. So I also got the 0.87 because I was using a dark color

Answer (score 1):

It happens only with **M2** and it doesn't depends on the `Surface`, but on the `Text` itself.

The color in the `Text` is defined by the `color` parameter or applying a `TextStyle`. The default value is [**`Color.Unspecified`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Unspecified()).
If color = `Color.Unspecified` and style has no color set, this will be [**`LocalContentColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#LocalContentColor()) mixed with `LocalContentAlpha.current`.

In the Text.kt you can find:

```
val textColor = color.takeOrElse {
        style.color.takeOrElse {
            LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
        }
    }
```

As you described in your answer in the MaterialTheme is defined:

```
fun MaterialTheme( /* .. */ ) {
    //...
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high, //0.87f
        //...
    )
```

In **M3** (`androidx.compose.material3`) it doesn't happen since `LocalContentColor.current` is not mixed:

```
val textColor = color.takeOrElse {
    style.color.takeOrElse {
        LocalContentColor.current
    }
}
```

[image]